# Accessing class level member without an instance of the class

Tags: python

Is it possible to access a class member without an instance of the class? For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    MyMember = 1

class MyOtherClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print MyClass.MyMember  #MyClass().MyMember works out but not MyClass.MyMember
```

I'm looking for something synonymous with static class members in C++.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Note that by convention MixedCase is only used for class names in Python.  Member variables and method names use `lower_case_with_underscores`.

Comment: What doesn't work about what you have?  What are you expecting?  The code you have runs, so you should be more explicit about what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  [Your code works.](http://ideone.com/17F9w)

Comment: Odd, PyDev complains about it in the editor. Apoligies for the redundant question.

Comment: @Graeme: Never mind, and feel free to delete your question as long as this is still possible.  It's probably not very useful to others.

Comment: PyDev does not complain for me though...